# Export table to file with column headers (column names) using the bcp utility and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, csv, header, bcp

I have seen a number of hacks to try to get the bcp utility to export column names along with the data. If all I am doing is dumping a table to a text file what is the most straightforward method to have bcp add the column headers?

Here's the bcp command I am currently using:

```
bcp myschema.dbo.myTableout myTable.csv /SmyServer01 /c /t, -T
```

Comment: I used with clause along with a dummy column OrderCol  to guarantee the order. 

with temp as
(
SELECT 'colName1','colName2','colName3','colName4','colName5','colName6','colName7','colName8',1 OrderCol
Union all
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8, 2 OrderCol  FROM TableName  )
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8 from Temp 
order by OrderCol

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The easiest is to use the `queryout` option and use `union all` to link a column list with the actual table content

```
    bcp "select 'col1', 'col2',... union all select * from myschema.dbo.myTableout" queryout myTable.csv /SmyServer01 /c /t, -T
```

An example:

```
create table Question1355876
(id int, name varchar(10), someinfo numeric)

insert into Question1355876
values (1, 'a', 123.12)
     , (2, 'b', 456.78)
     , (3, 'c', 901.12)
     , (4, 'd', 353.76)
```

This query will return the information with the headers as first row (note the casts of the numeric values):

```
select 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'
union all
select cast(id as varchar(10)), name, cast(someinfo as varchar(28))
from Question1355876
```

The bcp command will be:

```
bcp "select 'col1', 'col2', 'col3' union all select cast(id as varchar(10)), name, cast(someinfo as varchar(28)) from Question1355876" queryout myTable.csv /SmyServer01 /c /t, -T
```

Comment: Throws an error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'COL001' to data type int.

Comment: I added an example which contains numeric values. You need to cast the numeric columns to varchar (or nvarchar)

Comment: Order By clause fails !

Comment: `order by` is perfectly supported by this. If you encounter an error it must be in your sql statement.

Comment: this does not work if datatypes are int in source table

Comment: Cast the columns to varchar in the query.

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik, just to confirm, you're talking about getting an error like `Unable to resolve column level collations`, right?

Comment: you can't concat numbers & strings and some other types. To do that you need to cast. Columns with different collations probably also throw errors.

Comment: You have to do a bit more coding if you want to sort the data, but not have the columns included in the sort.

Answer (score 67):

This method automatically outputs column names with your row data using [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms162802.aspx).

The script writes one file for the column headers (read from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table) then appends another file with the table data.

The final output is combined into `TableData.csv` which has the headers and row data.  Just replace the environment variables at the top to specify the Server, Database and Table name.

```
set BCP_EXPORT_SERVER=put_my_server_name_here
set BCP_EXPORT_DB=put_my_db_name_here
set BCP_EXPORT_TABLE=put_my_table_name_here

BCP "DECLARE @colnames VARCHAR(max);SELECT @colnames = COALESCE(@colnames + ',', '') + column_name from %BCP_EXPORT_DB%.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='%BCP_EXPORT_TABLE%'; select @colnames;" queryout HeadersOnly.csv -c -T -S%BCP_EXPORT_SERVER%

BCP %BCP_EXPORT_DB%.dbo.%BCP_EXPORT_TABLE% out TableDataWithoutHeaders.csv -c -t, -T -S%BCP_EXPORT_SERVER%

set BCP_EXPORT_SERVER=
set BCP_EXPORT_DB=
set BCP_EXPORT_TABLE=

copy /b HeadersOnly.csv+TableDataWithoutHeaders.csv TableData.csv

del HeadersOnly.csv
del TableDataWithoutHeaders.csv
```

Note that if you need to supply credentials, replace the -T option with -U my_username -P my_password

This method has the advantage of always having the column names in sync with the table by using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.  The downside is that it creates temporary files.  Microsoft should really fix the bcp utility to support this.

This solution uses the SQL row concatenation trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) combined with bcp ideas from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/812b8eec-5b77-42a2-bd23-965558ece5b9/)

Comment: I use `select substring(@colnames,2,1000000000);` instead of `select @colnames;` because the `@colnames` variable is printed with a coma at the begining of the headers.

Comment: Awesome script dude. I would vote up twice if I could. Any way to make the names of the tables and databases as batch script variables?

Comment: @CrazyTim, I've made the names env variables for ease of use. Glad it's of use to you.

Comment: I get this error when I try it: Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Host-file columns may be skipped only when
 copying into the Server

Comment: @thchaver what version of SQL Server are you using? This issue may be related to SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 27):

For:

- Windows, 64 bit
- SQL Server (tested with [SQL Server 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2017) and it should work for all versions):

### Option 1: Command Prompt

```
sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; select * from [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLENAME]" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "c:\dirname\file.csv"
```

Where:

- `[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLENAME]` is table to write.
- `c:\dirname\file.csv` is file to write to (surrounded in quotes to handle a path with spaces).
- Output .csv file includes headers.

Note: I tend to avoid `bcp`: it is legacy, it predates `sqlcmd` by a decade, and it never seems to work without causing a whole raft of headaches.

### Option 2: Within SQL Script

```
-- Export table [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLENAME] to .csv file c:\dirname\file.csv
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; select * from [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLENAME]" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "c:\dirname\file.csv"'
```

Troubleshoooting: must [enable xp_cmdshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131491/enable-xp-cmdshell-sql-server) within MSSQL.

### Sample Output

File: `file.csv`:

```
ID,Name,Height
1,Bob,192
2,Jane,184
3,Harry,186
```

### Speed

As fast as theoretically possible: same speed as `bcp`, and many times faster than manually exporting from SSMS.

### Parameter Explanation (optional - can ignore)

In `sqlcmd`:

- `-s,` puts a comma between each column.

- `-W` eliminates padding either side of the values.
- `set nocount on` eliminates a garbage line at the end of the query.

For `findstr`:

- All this does is remove the second line underline underneath the header, e.g. `--- ----- ---- ---- ----- --`.
- `/v /c:"-"` matches any line that starts with "-".
- `/b` returns all other lines.

### Importing into other programs

In Excel:

- Can directly open the file in Excel.

In Python:

```
import pandas as pd
df_raw = pd.read_csv("c:\dirname\file.csv")
```

Comment: This is great. I particularly like how it's a single line of SQL to run the export. I will probably start using this instead of bcp. Only thing to watch out for is if any of your values in column 1 start with "-" they will be removed from the export. Could get messy for negative numbers converted to varchar.

Comment: This is great. Helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: Nice one, worked like a charm.  Just need to figure out how to remove NULL and replace with space or nothing, but a find/replace will sort that out.

Comment: Really clever. So basically bcp must die ?

Comment: I just taught myself how to use BCP but why?  with @Contango's option 2? lol

Comment: Great alternative to the original request for help with BCP. A very well written post. Thank you @contango

Answer (score 15):

A good alternative is SqlCmd, since it does include headers, but it has the downside of adding space padding around the data for human readability.  You can combine SqlCmd with the GnuWin32 sed (stream editing) utility to cleanup the results.  Here's an example that worked for me, though I can't guarantee that it's bulletproof.

First, export the data:

```
sqlcmd -S Server -i C:\Temp\Query.sql -o C:\Temp\Results.txt -s"    "
```

The `-s"    "` is a tab character in double quotes.  I found that you have to run this command via a batch file, otherwise the Windows command prompt will treat the tab as an automatic completion command and will substitute a filename in place of the tab.

If Query.sql contains:

```
SELECT name, object_id, type_desc, create_date
FROM MSDB.sys.views
WHERE name LIKE 'sysmail%'
```

then you'll see something like this in Results.txt

> ```
> name                                          object_id   type_desc           create_date            
> -------------------------------------------   ----------- ------------------- -----------------------
> sysmail_allitems                               2001442204 VIEW                2012-07-20 17:38:27.820
> sysmail_sentitems                              2017442261 VIEW                2012-07-20 17:38:27.837
> sysmail_unsentitems                            2033442318 VIEW                2012-07-20 17:38:27.850
> sysmail_faileditems                            2049442375 VIEW                2012-07-20 17:38:27.860
> sysmail_mailattachments                        2097442546 VIEW                2012-07-20 17:38:27.933
> sysmail_event_log                              2129442660 VIEW                2012-07-20 17:38:28.040
>
> (6 rows affected)
> ```

Next, parse the text using sed:

```
sed -r "s/ +\t/\t/g" C:\Temp\Results.txt | sed -r "s/\t +/\t/g" | sed -r "s/(^ +| +$)//g" | sed 2d | sed $d | sed "/^$/d" > C:\Temp\Results_New.txt
```

Note that the `2d` command means to delete the second line, the `$d` command means to delete the last line, and `"/^$/d"` deletes any blank lines.

The cleaned up file looks like this (though I replaced the tabs with `|` so they could be visualized here):

> ```
> name|object_id|type_desc|create_date
> sysmail_allitems|2001442204|VIEW|2012-07-20 17:38:27.820
> sysmail_sentitems|2017442261|VIEW|2012-07-20 17:38:27.837
> sysmail_unsentitems|2033442318|VIEW|2012-07-20 17:38:27.850
> sysmail_faileditems|2049442375|VIEW|2012-07-20 17:38:27.860
> sysmail_mailattachments|2097442546|VIEW|2012-07-20 17:38:27.933
> sysmail_event_log|2129442660|VIEW|2012-07-20 17:38:28.040
> ```

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to figure how to do this recently and while I like the most popular solution at the top, it simply would not work for me as I needed the names to be the alias's that I entered in the script so I used some batch files (with some help from a colleague) to accomplish custom table names.

The batch file that initiates the bcp has a line at the bottom of the script that executes another script that merges a template file with the header names and the file that was just exported with bcp using the code below. Hope this helps someone else that was in my situation.

```
echo Add headers from template file to exported sql files....
Echo School 0031
copy e:\genin\templates\TEMPLATE_Courses.csv + e:\genin\0031\courses0031.csv e:\genin\finished\courses0031.csv /b
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Just remember you don't have to do this from a batch file, you can call the copy command using 'xp_cmdshell' as well, if that's how you are calling BCP anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue. I needed to export the column header using SQL server bcp utility.This way I exported table "headers" with data into same exported file in one go.

```
DECLARE @table_name  VARCHAR(50) ='mytable'
DECLARE @columnHeader VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @columnHeader = COALESCE(@columnHeader+',' ,'')+ ''''+column_name +'''' FROM Nal2013.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=@table_name
SELECT @raw_sql = 'bcp "SELECT '+ @columnHeader +' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM mytable" queryout c:\datafile.csv -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername
EXEC  xp_cmdshell @raw_sql
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: what if the data types are different

Comment: if the data types are different, CAST anything in your SELECT to VARCHAR which isn't already a VARCHAR or NVARCHAR. Since you're writing to .CSV anyway, then it won't make any different to the output.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pretty simple stored procedure that does the trick as well...

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetBCPTable
    @table_name varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @raw_sql nvarchar(3000)

    DECLARE @columnHeader VARCHAR(8000)
    SELECT @columnHeader = COALESCE(@columnHeader+',' ,'')+ ''''+column_name +'''' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name

    DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(8000)
    SELECT @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList+',' ,'')+ 'CAST('+column_name +' AS VARCHAR)' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name

    SELECT @raw_sql = 'SELECT '+ @columnHeader +' UNION ALL SELECT ' + @ColumnList + ' FROM ' + @table_name
    --PRINT @raw_SQL
    EXECUTE sp_executesql  @raw_sql
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Everyone's versions do things a little different.  This is the version that I have developed over the years. This version seems to account for all of the issues I have encountered.  Simply populate a data set into a table then pass the table name to this stored procedure.

I call this stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC    @return_value = *DB_You_Create_The_SP_In*.[dbo].[Export_CSVFile]
        @DB = N'*YourDB*',
        @TABLE_NAME = N'*YourTable*',
        @Dir = N'*YourOutputDirectory*',
        @File = N'*YourOutputFileName*'
```

There are also two other variables:

- @NullBlanks -- This will take any field that doesn't have a value and
  null it.  This is useful because in the true sense of the CSV
  specification each data point should have quotes around them.  If you
  have a large data set this will save you a fair amount of space by
  not having "" (two double quotes) in those fields. If you don't find this useful then set it to 0.
- @IncludeHeaders -- I have one stored procedure for outputting CSV
  files, so I do have    that flag in the event I don't want headers.

This will create the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Export_CSVFile] 
(@DB varchar(128),@TABLE_NAME varchar(128), @Dir varchar(255), @File varchar(250),@NULLBLANKS bit=1,@IncludeHeader bit=1)
AS

DECLARE @CSVHeader varchar(max)=''  --CSV Header
, @CmdExc varchar(8000)=''          --EXEC commands
, @SQL varchar(max)=''              --SQL Statements
, @COLUMN_NAME varchar(128)=''      --Column Names
, @DATA_TYPE varchar(15)=''         --Data Types

DECLARE @T table (COLUMN_NAME varchar(128),DATA_TYPE varchar(15))

--BEGIN Ensure Dir variable has a backslash as the final character
IF NOT RIGHT(@Dir,1) = '\' BEGIN SET @Dir=@Dir+'\' END
--END

--BEGIN Drop TEMP Table IF Exists
SET @SQL='IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''TEMP_'+@TABLE_NAME+''')) BEGIN EXEC(''DROP TABLE ['+@DB+'].[dbo].[TEMP_'+@TABLE_NAME+']'') END'
EXEC(@SQL)
--END

SET @SQL='SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME ='''+@TABLE_NAME+''' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION'
INSERT INTO @T
EXEC (@SQL)

SET @SQL=''
WHILE exists(SELECT * FROM @T)
    BEGIN
        SELECT top(1) @DATA_TYPE=DATA_TYPE,@COLUMN_NAME=COLUMN_NAME FROM @T
        IF @DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%' OR @DATA_TYPE LIKE '%text'
            BEGIN 
            IF @NULLBLANKS = 1
                BEGIN
                    SET @SQL+='CASE PATINDEX(''%[0-9,a-z]%'','+@COLUMN_NAME+') WHEN ''0'' THEN NULL ELSE ''"''+RTRIM(LTRIM('+@COLUMN_NAME+'))+''"'' END AS ['+@COLUMN_NAME+'],' 
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @SQL+='''"''+RTRIM(LTRIM('+@COLUMN_NAME+'))+''"'' AS ['+@COLUMN_NAME+'],' 
                END
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN SET @SQL+=@COLUMN_NAME+',' END
            SET @CSVHeader+='"'+@COLUMN_NAME+'",'
            DELETE top(1) @T
    END 

IF LEN(@CSVHeader)>1 BEGIN SET @CSVHeader=RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(@CSVHeader,LEN(@CSVHeader)-1))) END

IF LEN(@SQL)>1 BEGIN SET @SQL= 'SELECT '+ LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL)-1) + ' INTO ['+@DB+'].[dbo].[TEMP_'+@TABLE_NAME+'] FROM ['+@DB+'].[dbo].['+@TABLE_NAME+']' END
EXEC(@SQL)

IF @IncludeHeader=0 
    BEGIN
        --BEGIN Create Data file
        SET  @CmdExc ='BCP "'+@DB+'.dbo.TEMP_'+@TABLE_NAME+'" out "'+@Dir+'Data_'+@TABLE_NAME+'.csv" /c /t, -T' 
        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CmdExc
        --END
        SET  @CmdExc ='del '+@Dir+@File EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CmdExc
        SET  @CmdExc ='ren '+@Dir+'Data_'+@TABLE_NAME+'.csv '+@File EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CmdExc
    END 
else
    BEGIN

        --BEGIN Create Header and main file
        SET  @CmdExc ='echo '+@CSVHeader+'> '+@Dir+@File EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CmdExc
        --END

        --BEGIN Create Data file
        SET  @CmdExc ='BCP "'+@DB+'.dbo.TEMP_'+@TABLE_NAME+'" out "'+@Dir+'Data_'+@TABLE_NAME+'.csv" /c /t, -T' 
        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CmdExc
        --END

        --BEGIN Merge Data File With Header File
        SET @CmdExc = 'TYPE '+@Dir+'Data_'+@TABLE_NAME+'.csv >> '+@Dir+@File EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CmdExc
        --END

        --BEGIN Delete Data File
        SET @CmdExc = 'DEL /q '+@Dir+'Data_'+@TABLE_NAME+'.csv' EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CmdExc
        --END
    END
--BEGIN Drop TEMP Table IF Exists
SET @SQL='IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''TEMP_'+@TABLE_NAME+''')) BEGIN EXEC(''DROP TABLE ['+@DB+'].[dbo].[TEMP_'+@TABLE_NAME+']'') END'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks!
With "@CmdExc varchar(max)" was getting these errors:
Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'. So changed from max to 8000 and it works

Answer (score 3):

Some of the solutions here are overly complex. Here's one with 4 lines of code, no batch files, no external apps and all self-contained in the SQL server.

In this example, my table is named "MyTable" and it has two columns named Column1 and Column2. Column2 is an integer, so we need to CAST it to varchar for the export:

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(100)
DECLARE @BCPCommand varchar(8000)
DECLARE @ColumnHeader varchar(8000)

    SET @FileName = 'C:\Temp\OutputFile.csv'
 SELECT @ColumnHeader = COALESCE(@ColumnHeader+',' ,'')+ ''''+column_name +'''' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTable'
    SET @BCPCommand = 'bcp "SELECT '+ @ColumnHeader +' UNION ALL SELECT Column1, CAST(Column2 AS varchar(100)) AS Column2 FROM MyTable" queryout "' + @FileName + '" -c -t , -r \n  -S . -T'
   EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @BCPCommand
```

You could add this to a stored procedure to fully automate your .CSV file (with header row) creation.

Answer (score 2):

From all I know, BCP only exports the data - I don't think there's any way to make it export the header row with column names, too.

One common technique seen to solve this is to use a view over your actual data for export, which basically does a UNION ALL over two statements:

- the first statement to give back one row with the column headers
- the actual data to be export

and then use bcp on that view, instead of your underlying data table directly.

Marc

Comment: Not a terrible solution, but this would mean you need to create a view for every type of .CSV file you want to export, and modify both the view and the BCP command when you wanted to change fields, column names etc. Using Dynamic SQL and performing the UNION as part of a dynamic statement rather than in a view is much more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the solution from marc_s, you can also use [osql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806%28SQL.90%29.aspx) or [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

This includes headers and it can act like bcp using -Q and -o. However, they don't support format files like bcp.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to solve this problem with one cte view and one batch file containing the bcp code. First create the view. Since, it's relatively straightforward, I did not create a temporary table. Normally I do

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwxMySAMPLE_EXTRACT_COLUMNS]
  AS
    WITH MYBCP_CTE (COLUMN_NM, ORD_POS, TXT)
     AS
      ( SELECT  COLUMN_NAME
             , ORDINAL_POSITION
             , CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'xMySAMPLE_EXTRACT_NEW'
        AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  V.COLUMN_NAME
              , V.ORDINAL_POSITION
              , CAST(C.TXT + '|' + V.COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]  V INNER JOIN MYBCP_CTE C
        ON V.ORDINAL_POSITION = C.ORD_POS+1
        AND V.ORDINAL_POSITION > 1
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'xMySAMPLE_EXTRACT_NEW'
      )

      SELECT CC.TXT
      FROM MYBCP_CTE CC INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(ORD_POS) AS MX_CNT
                                     FROM MYBCP_CTE C
                                    ) SC
      ON CC.ORD_POS = SC.MX_CNT
```

Now, create the batch file. I created this in my Temp directory, but I'm lazy.

```
  cd\
  CD "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"

  set buildhour=%time: =0%
  set buildDate=%DATE:~4,10%
  set backupfiledate=%buildDate:~6,4%%buildDate:~0,2%%buildDate:~3,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

  echo %backupfiledate%
  pause
```

The above code just creates a date to append to the end of your file... Next, the first bcp statement with the view to the recursive cte to concatenate it all together.

```
  bcp "SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[vwxMYSAMPLE_EXTRACT_COLUMNS] OPTION (MAXRECURSION 300)" queryout C:\Temp\Col_NM%backupfiledate%.txt -c -t"|" -S MYSERVERTOLOGINTO -T -q
  bcp "SELECT *  FROM [myDBName].[dbo].[vwxMYSAMPLE_EXTRACT_NEW] " queryout C:\Temp\3316_PHYSDATA_ALL%backupfiledate%.txt -c -t"|" -S MYSERVERTOLOGINTO -T -q
```

Now merge them together using the copy command:

```
  copy C:\Temp\Col_NM%backupfiledate%.txt  + C:\Temp\3316_PHYSDATA_ALL%backupfiledate%.txt  C:\Temp\3316_PHYSDATA_ALL%backupfiledate%.csv
```

All set

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of sqlcmd adds the `-w` option to remove extra space after the field value; however, it does *not* put quotes around strings, which can be a problem with [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files when importing a field value that contains a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below another way to make the same thing.

This procedure also takes in a schema name as a parameter in case you need it to access your table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Export_Data_NBA
@TableName nchar(50),
@TableSchema nvarchar(50) = ''

AS
DECLARE @TableToBeExported as nvarchar(50);

DECLARE @OUTPUT TABLE (col1 nvarchar(max));
DECLARE @colnamestable VARCHAR(max);
select @colnamestable = COALESCE(@colnamestable, '') 
+COLUMN_NAME+ ','
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = @TableName
order BY ORDINAL_POSITION

SELECT @colnamestable = LEFT(@colnamestable,DATALENGTH(@colnamestable)-1)

INSERT INTO @OUTPUT
select @colnamestable

DECLARE @selectstatement VARCHAR(max);
select @selectstatement = COALESCE(@selectstatement, '') 
       + 'Convert(nvarchar(100),'+COLUMN_NAME+')+'',''+'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName
order BY ORDINAL_POSITION

SELECT @selectstatement = LEFT(@selectstatement,DATALENGTH(@selectstatement)-1)

DECLARE @sqlstatment as nvarchar(max);

SET @TableToBeExported = @TableSchema+'.'+@TableToBeExported

SELECT @sqlstatment = N'Select '+@selectstatement+N' 
  from '+@TableToBeExported

INSERT INTO @OUTPUT
exec sp_executesql @stmt = @sqlstatment

SELECT * from @OUTPUT
```

Comment: the only thing this does is to return the columns of a table.

Comment: keep improving your sql - constance and determination, answer more questions

Answer (score 1):

I got a version based on what I saw previously.  It helped me a lot to create export files as CSV or TXT.  I'm storing a table into a ## Temp Table:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TmpExportFile') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##TmpExportFile;


DECLARE @columnHeader VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @raw_sql nvarchar(3000)

SELECT
              * INTO ##TmpExportFile
              ------ FROM THE TABLE RESULTS YOU WANT TO GET
              ------ COULD BE A TABLE OR A TEMP TABLE BASED ON INNER JOINS
              ------ ,ETC.

FROM TableName -- optional WHERE ....


DECLARE @table_name  VARCHAR(50) = '##TmpExportFile'
SELECT
              @columnHeader = COALESCE(@columnHeader + ',', '') + '''[' + c.name + ']''' + ' as ' + '' + c.name + ''
FROM tempdb.sys.columns c
INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.tables t
              ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.NAME = @table_name

print @columnheader

                DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(max)
SELECT
              @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList + ',', '') + 'CAST([' + c.name + '] AS CHAR(' + LTRIM(STR(max_length)) + '))'
FROM tempdb.sys.columns c
INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.tables t
              ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = @table_name
print @ColumnList

--- CSV FORMAT                                       
SELECT
              @raw_sql = 'bcp "SELECT ' + @columnHeader + ' UNION all SELECT ' + @ColumnList + ' FROM ' + @table_name + ' " queryout \\networkdrive\networkfolder\datafile.csv -c -t, /S' + ' SQLserverName /T'
--PRINT @raw_sql
EXEC xp_cmdshell @raw_sql

  --- TXT FORMAT
       SET @raw_sql = 'bcp "SELECT ' + @columnHeader + ' UNION all SELECT ' + @ColumnList + ' FROM ' + @table_name + ' " queryout \\networkdrive\networkfolder\MISD\datafile.txt /c /S'+ ' SQLserverName /T'
       EXEC xp_cmdshell @raw_sql



DROP TABLE ##TmpExportFile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @table_name varchar(max)='tableName'--which needs to be exported
DECLARE @fileName varchar(max)='file Name'--What would be file name

DECLARE @query varchar(8000)
DECLARE @columnHeader VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @columnHeader = COALESCE(@columnHeader+',' ,'')+ ''''
        +column_name +''''  
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name

DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList+',' ,'')
       + 'CAST('+column_name +' AS VARCHAR)' +column_name 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name

DECLARE @tempRaw_sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @tempRaw_sql = 'SELECT ' 
        + @ColumnList + ' into ##temp11 FROM ' 
        + @table_name 

PRINT @tempRaw_sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql  @tempRaw_sql


DECLARE @raw_sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @raw_sql = 'SELECT  '+ @columnHeader 
       +' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ##temp11'

PRINT @raw_SQL
SET @query='bcp "'+@raw_SQL+'" queryout "C:\data\'+@fileName
            +'.txt" -T -c -t,'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @query


DROP TABLE ##temp11
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: this is a bit raw but worked for me, does [the casting into varchar without length](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160747/22336) though

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully achieved this with the below code.
Put the below code in an SQL Server new query window and try:

```
CREATE TABLE tempDBTableDetails ( TableName VARCHAR(500), [RowCount] VARCHAR(500), TotalSpaceKB VARCHAR(500),
                UsedSpaceKB VARCHAR(500), UnusedSpaceKB VARCHAR(500) )

    -- STEP 1 ::
    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(4000)

INSERT INTO tempDBTableDetails
SELECT 'TableName', 'RowCount', 'TotalSpaceKB', 'UsedSpaceKB', 'UnusedSpaceKB'
INSERT INTO tempDBTableDetails
SELECT
    S.name +'.'+ T.name as TableName,
    Convert(varchar,Cast(SUM(P.rows) as Money),1) as [RowCount],
    Convert(varchar,Cast(SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 as Money),1) AS TotalSpaceKB,
    Convert(varchar,Cast(SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 as Money),1) AS UsedSpaceKB,
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM sys.tables T
INNER JOIN sys.partitions P ON P.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units A ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE T.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND P.index_id IN (1,0)
GROUP BY S.name, T.name
ORDER BY SUM(P.rows) DESC

-- SELECT * FROM [FIINFRA-DB-SIT].dbo.tempDBTableDetails ORDER BY LEN([RowCount]) DESC

SET @cmd = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [FIINFRA-DB-SIT].dbo.tempDBTableDetails ORDER BY LEN([RowCount]) DESC" queryout "D:\Milind\export.xls" -U sa -P dbowner -c'
    Exec xp_cmdshell @cmd

--DECLARE @HeaderCmd VARCHAR(4000)
--SET @HeaderCmd = 'SELECT ''TableName'', ''RowCount'', ''TotalSpaceKB'', ''UsedSpaceKB'', ''UnusedSpaceKB'''
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT ''TableName'', ''RowCount'', ''TotalSpaceKB'', ''UsedSpaceKB'', ''UnusedSpaceKB''" queryout "d:\milind\header.xls" -U sa -P dbowner -c'
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'copy /b "d:\Milind\header.xls"+"d:\Milind\export.xls" "d:/Milind/result.xls"'

exec master..xp_cmdshell 'del "d:\Milind\header.xls"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'del "d:\Milind\export.xls"'

DROP TABLE tempDBTableDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little PowerShell script:

```html
sqlcmd -Q "set nocount on select top 0 * from [DB].[schema].[table]" -o c:\temp\header.txt
bcp [DB].[schema].[table] out c:\temp\query.txt -c -T -S BRIZA
Get-Content c:\temp\*.txt | Set-Content c:\temp\result.txt
Remove-Item c:\temp\header.txt
Remove-Item c:\temp\query.txt
```

Warning: The concatenation follows the .txt file name (in alphabetical order)

Answer (score 0):

Just used this for a DB Migration Activity.
Helped a great bit - given that its a single line.
I simply put this in the SQL Management Studio

```html
SELECT 'sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; select * from [dbname].[dbo].['+ st.NAME + ']" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b >' + st.NAME + '.csv' + FROM sys.tables st
```

Copied the resultant set into a .bat file and I can now export the entire DB with each table into a CSV.