# SQL Server Limit Allowed Hosts

Tags: mysql, sql-server

In MySQL, I can set which hosts are allowed to connect to the server in the config file. Is there a way to do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do all this via

- SQL Server Management Studio
- directly over SQL ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms173463.aspx )

You can give access for domain users, groups or just create an independent user. There's lots information in the web so feel free to google some howtos.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't specific enough: I want to limit the connection based on a user name/host name combination, like it is in MySQL.

Comment: so the user can just see specified databases, tables ?

Comment: I'm not worried about limiting access to specific tables or database, I know how to do this.
I want to be able to say userA@IP is allowed access to this database. Connections from any other IP are not allowed

Comment: Ah ok, now i understand what you are searching for. Haven't seen this in SQL Server so far, maybe have a look at this and see if its an option for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127602/restrict-sql-server-connection-to-specific-ip-address