# SQL Server 2008 Query Result to XML FIle

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I'm having some trouble dumping a query result into a XML file. I've read many articles about this subject but i still can't reach a decent solution for my case.

I have a procedure that outputs a query in XML format and it's working well:

```
alter proc pr_export_xml
as
declare @XmlOutput xml
set @XmlOutput = (select id,ref,sit from RepData for XML PATH('Produto'), ROOT('Produtos'), TYPE)

select @XmlOutput
go
```

What I need now is to get that result and dump into a file for later use. This procedure will be called during a trigger, so the dump into file must be done automatically.

I hope I was clear enough, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Second part of this article is probably what you need http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/create-xml-files-out-of-sql-server-with-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative for this one is bcp utility.

Look into these.

*http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/119542.aspx*

 *[Enable 'xp_cmdshell' SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131491/enable-xp-cmdshell-sql-server)*