# SQL Server : export from file.sql to a flat file

Tags: sql, sql-server, export-to-csv

I am looking for assistance in performing an export of data via an SQL Server query into a flat file which is delimited by a `|` (pipe).
I have done this in Sybase SQL without problems using the `OUTPUT` function within my code:

```
SELECT ItemName
FROM Products
WHERE ItemName = 'Gizmo'
; OUTPUT TO Z:\Export.txt FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY '\xA6'
```

Does SQL Server have such a function and if so, how it is used?

**Update**

I should have clarified this a bit more. I would like to execute this `file.sql` statement via a VB Script in order to make a manual process into an automated one. Any manual functions within SQL Server Management Studio will not work. `xp_cmdshell` is not an option either as the DBA will not allow it.

Answer (score 5):

1. In SSMS go to Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Text
2. On this pane choose Output format: Customer delimiter, and enter '|'
3. Return to your query and select Query -> Results to File (Ctrl+Shift+F)
4. Execute your query, you will be asked to select the file path and name

File will be saved with a .rpt extension, you can alter it to .txt

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update:

> I should have clarified this a bit more. I would like to execute this
>   file.sql statement via a VB Script in order to make a manual process
>   into an automated one. Any manual functions within SQL Server
>   Management Studio will not work. xp_cmdshell is not an option either
>   as the DBA will not allow it.

Will your DBA allow you to use SSIS (or Data Tools) and do have that capability?  ***If so***, you can create a `DATA FLOW` task in SSIS (or Data Tools) that will export the query to a flat file, have a job call the package, and your VB script execute `sp_start_job` to execute the job that calls the package.

Answer (score 1):

I have to export querys into flatfiles all the time so this is my solution. 
Basically I create a procedure that has the Query (remember to put in tables full name),
File Name, Dir Path as parameters. Values are separated by "|" by default but you can
change it..

Don't know if these are best practices or not, It works for me and security is not
a issue with the db's I'm working with.

[BCP utillity](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/) does the trick almost by itself.. Before creating the procedure be sure to set the right permissions: [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121(v=sql.110).aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131491/enable-xp-cmdshell-sql-server).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[export_table] 
@query VARCHAR(8000)
,@out_file VARCHAR(8000)
,@out_dir VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @temp NVARCHAR(4000)
  DECLARE @query_body VARCHAR(8000)
  DECLARE @header VARCHAR(8000)
  DECLARE @full_header VARCHAR(8000)
  DECLARE @copy VARCHAR(8000)
  DECLARE @del VARCHAR(8000)
  DECLARE @del1 VARCHAR(8000)

  -- CREATE AND EXPORT BODY

  -- drop temp table (when running procedure in same instance)

  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE ##temp 

  -- populate temp with just 1 line so we can take out the header

  SET @temp = 'SELECT TOP 1 * INTO ##temp FROM (' + COALESCE(@query,'') + ') a'  

  -- set up the bcp query removing idents so you dont have to write the query in one line

  SET @query_body = 'bcp "' + COALESCE(@query,'') + '" queryout ' + @out_dir + 'qBody.txt -CACP -T -c -t"|" '
  SET @query_body = REPLACE(REPLACE(@query_body, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @temp
  EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @query_body

  -- CREATE AND EXPORT HEADER

  -- set the header using system tables and 
  -- temp table previously created (alias = name) and use bcp to expor the header 

  SELECT @header = 
    COALESCE(@header + ''', ', '') + '''' + name  
    FROM (
      SELECT name 
      FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
      WHERE 
        object_id = object_id('tempdb..##temp') 
    ) b
  SET @header = @header + ''''
  SET @full_header = 'bcp "select '+ @header +'" queryout ' + @out_dir + 'qHeader.txt -CACP -T -c -t"|" '

  -- COPY NEW FILE FROM HEADER AND BODY AND DELETE USED FILES (USING WINDOWS CMD) 

  SET @copy = 'copy /b "' + @out_dir + 'qHeader.txt" + "' + @out_dir + 'qBody.txt" "' + @out_dir + @out_file + '.txt"'
  SET @del = 'del "' + @out_dir + 'qHeader.txt"'
  SET @del1 = 'del "' + @out_dir + 'qBody.txt"'
  EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @full_header
  EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @copy
  EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @del
  EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @del1
END

GO

-- EXEMAPLE OF USAGE

exec export_table
'select 
    column1
    ,column2 as ''escape_quotes'' 
from cnes.dbo.stg_vinculo'
,'file_name'
,'C:\'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command:

```
Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM test12" queryout "c:\tempexportfile.txt" -c -T -f "c:\Fotmat.txt"'
```

where -f is there for a format file. This is the link on how to create a format file.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx