# How can I loop through all the files in a folder using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, import

We have a folder of excel files that we want to import into our database using TSQL. We have the code to import the individual file using `OpenRowSet`, but need to find a way to loop through the files in the folder and run this code on each file. How can this be accomplished using TSQL?

Answer (score 16):

Did some research, and found a way to loop over the files using something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(excelFileName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /B c:\my\folder\path\';

declare @fileName varchar(100)

While (Select Count(*) From #tmp where excelFileName is not null) > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 @fileName = excelFileName From #tmp

    -- OPENROWSET processing goes here, using @fileName to identify which file to use

    Delete from #tmp Where excelFileName = @FileName

End

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: Add `/s` to the `dir` command so the query is independent of the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for this script. It really helped me a lot. Cheers

Answer (score 8):

Adding More to What Froadie said, you likely need to first enable use of the command shell ([Enable 'xp_cmdshell' SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131491/enable-xp-cmdshell-sql-server)) also your cmd shell path may need to have double quotes around it, This is an example that I got to work:

```
--Allow for SQL to use cmd shell
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1    -- To allow advanced options to be changed.
RECONFIGURE -- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1  -- To enable the feature.
RECONFIGURE -- To update the currently configured value for this feature.

--Loop through all of the files
CREATE TABLE #tmp(excelFileName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /B "C:\_GENERAL RESOURCES\CANWET\ANUSPLINE DATA CONVERTER\AnusplineStationSelector\CCDP\Files\"';

declare @fileName varchar(100)

While (Select Count(*) From #tmp where excelFileName is not null) > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 @fileName = excelFileName From #tmp

    PRINT(@filename)
    -- OPENROWSET processing goes here, using @fileName to identify which file to use

    Delete from #tmp Where excelFileName = @FileName

End
```

Answer (score 0):

Very small improvement would be to add the following for repeatability.

```
--Loop through all of the files
drop table if exists #tmp
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35369676)