# New to SQL, how can I import multiple .CSV files?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, import, ssis

I'm new to SQL with a background in OOL type programming.

I've created the following query which successfully imports .CSV files into a table on SQL Management Studio. How would I go about importing multiple files? This would be quite straightforward using an OOL language, although I heard you have to read directories using cmd?

The working code is as following:

```
--Cihans Import for Holdings-- 
INSERT INTO Holdings1
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}
;DBQ=C:\Share\DataUploads\FundHoldings;','SELECT * FROM holdings.csv')
```

How would I go about looping/reading all files in a directory and importing data? We are given over 120 sheets a month, and I would like to import using the above. Or if anyone can recommend an alternative to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to SSIS? (SQL Server Integration Services)?

If so you can set up an ETL task using this to import all files in a folder using a `FOREACH LOOP CONTAINER` which contains your data flow task & file system task?

Edit - Response to comment - The Solution in this thread should enable you to do what you need using just T-SQL: [loop through files in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096057/how-can-i-loop-through-all-the-files-in-a-folder-using-tsql)

Basically - load all the files into a temptable, create a while loop, passing in a new filename from the folder each execution, then perform your data manipulation, then pass in the next filename until all are complete.

Comment: That's a really good idea, and I totally agree with you. 

The lead mathematical programmer is not too keen on SSIS since he prefers less add-ons etc. 

Therefore, I'm left in a position where I don't know how I would do this; the only option being TSQL that would do it for me.