# Use "Enter" as column or field separator in SQLCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd, data-export

What I need to do:

- I want to export data from SQL Server 2008 to a `CSV` in specific format.
- I *can't* use the `BCP` utility for this.
- I have exported `CSV` File using `SQLCMD` but the only issue is I need "Enter" as column or field separator in CSV file.
- Then I saved `SQLCMD` file as windows batch file and executed that using CMD

---

For Example, (Note: `test.sql` contains a `PLSql Block` which return columns data.):

1. I have saved below statement as batch file with name test.bat:

```
   sqlcmd -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 -v DatabaseName = %4 -i %current_dir%\test.sql -o %current_dir%\test.csv -y0 -I -s "
   "
```

2. Then executed above in CMD using below command:

```
   test.bat localhost user pass db_name
```

3. But it gives output like:

```
   ""REC"""LINE"
```

4. I want output like:

```
   "Rec"
   "LINE"
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: What's going to be line separator then?

Comment: "Enter" as column and line separator. Also SQLCMD by default use new line as row separator.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the reason you cannot use `BCP`?

Comment: BCP gives error of xp_cmdshell on our client. SQLCMD is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used this syntax in my table and when i opened the file it gived to me some kind of the result you are asking for. Just try it if it is what you are requiring.

```
 sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d Atrax_BazaRM -E -Q "select * from Njesite" -o "E:\MyData.csv" -h-1 -s "
    "
```

Comment: I have saved below statement as batch file: sqlcmd -S %1 -U %2 -P %3 -v DatabaseName = %4 -i %current_dir%\test.sql -o %current_dir%\test.csv -y0 -I -s " " Then execute this in cmd using: test.bat localhost user pass db_name.  But it gives output like: “"REC"”"LINE", and I want output like: “Rec”
“LINE”

Answer (score 0):

[Too long for comment]

You have in your list *I can't use the BCP utility for this.*. In the comment section you replied *BCP gives error of xp_cmdshell on our client.*.

You know you can enable use of `xp_cmdshell`, right? I'm not saying you *have* to and possibly the client won't agree. You can [enable `xp_cmdshell`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131503/243373) by:

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

After that you *can* use BCP and possibly this will make your problem easier to solve?

Comment: Thanks TT, I have already used above option, instead of this it is giving error on client machines. Just curious to know if this is possible with SQLCMD.

Comment: @JatinSingla I didn't understand your comment: *"I have already used above option, instead of this it is giving error on client machines"* > what exactly is giving an error? About SQLCMD, I think it's an ugly beast, I never use it so I can't really say whether it is possible in SQLCMD. I've searched on this issue online and like you I have not found anything about using newline as column separator.