# How to replace a word which has a specific pattern in text?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `ntext` (or `nvarchar(max)`) column which contains HTML text for **example**:

```html
<P>Hello <IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/1.JPG"></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<P><IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/folder1/2.JPG"></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P> World!
<P><IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/folder2/files/3.JPG"></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<P><IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/4.JPG"></P>
```

Now I need to replace each path of the `src` from `files/` to `files/new/` (or to other path) but only those with path of `files/`.

a `REPLACE` won't work (I think) because it would change also `files/folder1/` and `files/folder2/`.

In the above example, I need to only change the path for `1.JPG` and `4.JPG`.

How can I do it? *(The question is specific to sql-server)*.

Note: The file names/content can vary. the above HTML is just an example.

Comment: TSQL is not built for this, i.e. it's not possible.  Ideally this would be done in your domain/logic layer of your application, not in the data layer.

Comment: It should be easy to change from files to files/new

Comment: @RamGrandhi, read the question again. if I simply change `files` to `files/new` all 4 paths will be changed.

Comment: Is this a one-off update, or does your table store template HTML which is constantly updated?

Comment: @destination-data, the content can change. is there any difference?

Comment: Just thinking, if the HTML is only a template does it need to be valid?  Can you use a format like: `src=#fileLocation001#/1.jpg`.  This provides a handy replace target.  If a one-off I would use another language or find/replace.  If neither of these cases apply how often will you need to update?  Perhaps C#, using regex, inside an SSIS package is the way to go?

Comment: Did you already try to loop through your nvarchar(max) value linewise, analyse the line e.g. by counting the / between src and JPG and writing a new string? Afterwards you can writhe this new string to the DB, replacing the original Value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a quick approach in order to replace a certain pattern within a nvarchar(max) string. To be more precisely: the code takes a nvarchar(max) variable @x as source and writes the transformed string into a new variable @y. However, I wrote only the part of the string replacement - the "Update" still has to be coded.

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(max) = '<P>Hello <IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/1.JPG"></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<P><IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/folder1/2.JPG"></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P> World!
<P><IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/folder2/files/3.JPG"></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<P><IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/4.JPG"></P>'

DECLARE @brPos int = (SELECT CHARINDEX('</P>', @x));
DECLARE @brPosPrev int = 0;

DECLARE @srcPos int;
DECLARE @SlashPos int;
DECLARE @JPGPos int;

DECLARE @y nvarchar(max) = '';

DECLARE @xPart nvarchar(max);

WHILE (@brPos != 0)
BEGIN
  SET @xPart = SUBSTRING(@x, CASE WHEN @brPosPrev = 0 THEN @brPosPrev ELSE @brPosPrev END, @brPos-CASE WHEN @brPosPrev = 0 THEN @brPosPrev ELSE @brPosPrev END+4)

  SET @srcPos = (SELECT CHARINDEX('src="files/', @xPart))+11;
  SET @JPGPos = (SELECT CHARINDEX('.JPG', @xPart));
  SET @SlashPos = (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', @xPart, @srcPos));

  IF (@JPGPos < @SlashPos OR @SlashPos = 0)
    SET @xPart = REPLACE(@xPart, 'src="files/', 'src="files/new/');

  SET @y = @y + @xPart;

  SET @brPosPrev = @brPos + 4;
  SET @brPos = (SELECT CHARINDEX('</P>', @x, @brPosPrev));

END

SELECT @y
```

The Patterns I used in the CHARINDEX calls can be moved to variables as well - so you are not bound to use .JPG or whatever.

Comment: `@y` output has 8 `IMG` tags instead of 4. did I missed anything?  I'm also not sure why the `CHAR(10)` is needed. I will read the code more closely...

Comment: The char(10) is for the linebreaks in the nvarchar(max). You are right - to many tags... guess I missed something - give me a minute. I will check.

Comment: there is not necessary a line breaks in the content. it could be just `<P>Hello <IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/1.JPG">`. I'm also trying to follow your idea but my start pos is `"files/` and end pos is `"`.  I'm not  so concerned about the `src=` part.

Comment: I updated the code and use </P> as split criteria... at least @y looks OK now

Comment: Thanks, but the `</P>` is now removed completely. I still think the split should be done with the closing `"`

Comment: Oops, I missed to extend the length of the substring by 4 (in order to get </P> as well). However, using the " as split criteria would lead to new lines after alt=" and  title=" as well. That's why I used </P>. Code has been updated.

Comment: unfortunately `<P>` or `</P>` might not even be in the content as I already said. it could be just `Hello <IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/1.JPG">` or `<IMG title="" src="files/1.PNG" border=0 alt=""><BR> Hi`. note that the src might not be the last attribute. but the pattern `"files/[something]"` is always valid. I'm still trying to adjust your code without success.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because your approach helped me, and I have a solution now. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
DECLARE @input nvarchar(max) = 
'<P>Hello <IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/zzz/1.JPG"></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<P><IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/2.PNG"></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P> World!
<P><IMG title="" border=0 alt="" src="files/folder2/files/3.JEPG"></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<P><IMG title="" border=0 src="files/4.PNG" alt=""></P>'


DECLARE @path_old nvarchar(max) = 'files/';
DECLARE @path_new nvarchar(max) = 'files/new/';

DECLARE @i int, @j int;
DECLARE @path_len int = LEN(@path_old);
DECLARE @input_len int = LEN(@input);
DECLARE @start_location int = 1;
DECLARE @output nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @p nvarchar(max);

WHILE 1 = 1 
BEGIN
    SET @i = CHARINDEX('"' + @path_old, @input, @start_location) 
    IF @i <> 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @j = CHARINDEX('"', @input, @i + 1);
        SET @p = SUBSTRING(@input, @i + @path_len + 1, @j - @i - @path_len);
        IF CHARINDEX('/', @p) = 0  
            SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@input, @start_location - 1, @i + 2 - @start_location) + @path_new + @p 
        ELSE
            SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@input, @start_location - 1, @j + 2 - @start_location);           

        SET @start_location = @j + 2    
        IF @start_location >= @input_len BREAK;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@input, @start_location - 1, @input_len - @start_location + 2);
        BREAK;  
    END
END

PRINT @output
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 - 1 or 2 known file names**

If you only need to replace paths for `1.JPG` and `4.JPG`, then you can write an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE t
    SET html = REPLACE(REPLACE(html, 'src="files/4.JPG"', 'src="files/new/4.JPG"'), 'src="files/1.JPG"', 'src="files/new/1.JPG"')
FROM t
WHERE CHARINDEX('src="files/1.JPG"', html) + CHARINDEX('src="files/4.JPG"', html) > 0;
```

Or, if you'd rather keep them separate:

```
UPDATE t
    SET html = REPLACE(html, 'src="files/1.JPG"', 'src="files/new/1.JPG"')
FROM t
WHERE CHARINDEX('src="files/1.JPG"', html) > 0;


UPDATE t
    SET html = REPLACE(html, 'src="files/4.JPG"', 'src="files/new/4.JPG"')
FROM t
WHERE CHARINDEX('src="files/4.JPG"', html) > 0;
```

**Method 2 - potentially large list of files, whose names can be determined from the filesystem**

If you need to replace the paths for a large number of files, whose file names can be determined from the filesystem, try this instead:

1. Enable `xp_cmdshell` if required (see [Enable 'xp_cmdshell' SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131491/enable-xp-cmdshell-sql-server)).
2. Create a temporary table to store the file names:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #Images(
       Image_Name VARCHAR(100) NULL
   )
   ```
3. List all the files.

   ```
   INSERT INTO #Images
   exec xp_cmdshell 'dir D:\Data\*.jpg /b'
   ```
4. Remove NULL lines and anything else that's not required.

   ```
   DELETE FROM #Images
   WHERE Image_Name IS NULL
   ```
5. Generate SQL statements for each file name.

   ```
   SELECT '
       UPDATE t
           SET html = REPLACE(html, ''src="files/' + Image_Name + '"'', ''src="files/new/' + Image_Name + '"'')
       FROM t
       WHERE CHARINDEX(''src="files/' + Image_Name + '"'', html) > 0;
   '
   FROM #Images
   ```
6. Now simply copy-paste the output from executing the above `SELECT` statement back and execute the `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: Surely you need to understand that the content is dynamic. this HTML was just an example. 4.JPG can be foo.png or other...

Comment: I know. If it could be done **easily** I would have done it myself :)))