# SqlCmd command execution stops

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

Iam new to sqlcmd and i'm trying to execute this sql cmd code:

```
:Connect SERVERNAME
!!if exist $(FullBackup) del $(FullBackup)
GO
!!if exist $(TransactionLog) del $(TransactionLog)
GO
```

I am passing variables `$(FullBackup)` and `$(TransactionLog)` through a powershell script:

```
& $app -i $syncFileLocal -E -b -v FullBackup=("""$fullbackup""") TransactionLog=("""$transactionLog""");
```

where `syncFileLocal` contains the above sqlcmd command.

Somehow the execution stops after the second `:Connect PROD-SQLMASTER`

**UPDATE:**

When i use harcorded values for `$(FullBackup)` and `$(TransactionLog)`
the script seems to work. Is there anyway i could do it by passing variables through powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I recommend using this with appropriate validations

```
:Connect $(ServerMaster)
DECLARE @resultBkp INT
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist N'$(FullBackup)', @resultBkp OUTPUT
IF (@resultBkp = 1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @resultDeleteBkp INT
    EXECUTE master.sys.xp_cmdshell '$(FullBackup)'
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist N'$(FullBackup)', @resultDeleteBkp OUTPUT
    IF (@resultDeleteBkp = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Backup Deleted'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE();
        RETURN;
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Backup file not found'
END
```

I used the `master.dbo.xp_fileexist` to check whether the file exists and then used
`master.sys.xp_cmdshell` command to delete the file.

To enable `master.sys.xp_cmdshell` for the database server please use this solution:
[Enable 'xp_cmdshell' SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131491/enable-xp-cmdshell-sql-server)

I have tested it and it works fine when i pass the arguments via powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
FullBackup=("""$fullbackup""") TransactionLog=("""$transactionLog""")
```

try:

```
FullBackup="""$fullbackup""" TransactionLog="""$transactionLog"""
```

**If you use `()`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), its output is passed as a *separate* argument**, which is not what you want.

---

Do note, however, that even **the solution above relies on PowerShell's fundamentally broken argument-passing to external programs, as of v7.0** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

**If `sqlcmd` is implemented properly (I don't know if it is), the right way to pass the arguments is**:

```
FullBackup=$fullbackup TransactionLog=$transactionLog
```

That way, you would rely on PowerShell's on-demand, behind-the-scenes re-quoting of arguments, where if `$fullbackup` or `$translactionLog` contained spaces, the arguments would be passed as, for instance, `"FullBackup=c:\path\to\backup 1"` and `"TransactionLog=c:\path\to\log 1"`