# Sybase bcp doesn't export field headers?

Tags: sap-ase, bcp

Does anybody know to force sybase bcp to export column headers along with data?

The utility documentation curiously ignores this important feature..., perhaps I missing something.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this older post could give you some answers.

[export table to file with column headers (column names) using the bcp utility and SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355876/export-table-to-file-with-column-headers-column-names-using-the-bcp-utility-an)

BCP doesn't support a command line flag to add the headers unfortunately

Comment: The question is regarding Sybase, not SqlServer