# Add Headers name in the csv

Tags: csv, cmd, bcp

Goal:
I want to add some name of the column's header from stored procedure  to the CSV file

> bcp "EXEC [databasname].[storedprocedure]" queryout
>   C:\test\bcp_outputTable.csv -c -T -SPC01 -r\n

Problem:
I cannot find a solution to it.

Info:
I'm using the code above in CMD.

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355876/export-table-to-file-with-column-headers-column-names-using-the-bcp-utility-an

Comment: In this context I cannot change the code of the the stored procedure due to many reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @ECHO off
>
> SET "location=c:\test\" SET filename=%date:~0,10%
>
> ECHO This bat creates a csv file to the to the folder %location% ECHO
>   If you are ready, press the button space
>
> PAUSE
>
> BCP "[databasname].[storedprocedure]" queryout
>   %location%%filename%.txt -c -T -t; -SPC01 -r\n
>
> :: Adding header in the csv file ECHO f;f;f>
>   %location%%filename%.csv
>
> TYPE %location%%filename%.txt >> %location%%filename%.csv
>
> DEL /s %location%%filename%.txt
>
> PAUSE

Answer (score 1):

```
rename "C:\test\bcp_outputTable.csv" "C:\test\bcp_outputTable.txt"
echo HeadRow1,HeadRow2,HeadRow3,... >"C:\test\bcp_outputTable.csv"
type "C:\test\bcp_outputTable.txt>>"C:\test\bcp_outputTable.csv"
del "C:\test\bcp_outputTable.txt"
```