# How to get column name in excel using bcp format in sql

Tags: sql, csv, bcp

I already got the csv file with data but i need data with columns
I have many table which i need to execute at one go and save data in csv format at one location with header i don't want to add columns name as their 100 table.
I am using below query

```
Declare @cmd varchar(8000)
Set @cmd='Bcp"select * from tablename where condition queryout "path" -s -T -f -t, -c -E
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell
```

Their 100 tables like that.. any suggestion

Comment: you can't without a cludge such as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355876/export-table-to-file-with-column-headers-column-names-using-the-bcp-utility-an. BCP doesn't support exporting headers. Why do you need the headers? If it's for machine-to-machine transfer then the headers are irrelevant. If it's for presentation to the user then maybe bcp is not your best option - try out sqlcmd instead, or an SSIS package.

Comment: you are correct ADyson i did it with stored procedure..