# Export to CSV with Column Header using cmd shell and bcp

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

Database Name : `TESTING`
Table Name : `TEST`

```
Client_Code Client_Name Amount      
123             ABC      10     
456             PQR      20     
789             XYZ      30     
147             IJK      40
```

Required Output in CSV with Fallowing Header

```
Client Code Client Name Total balance       
123          ABC          10        
456          PQR          20        
789          XYZ          30        
147          IJK          40
```

I am using fallowing Query, But Result I am getting without Header

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from TESTING.dbo.TEST" queryout C:\queryoutput.csv -t"," -S"NEMP-HNI6101\SQLEXPRESS" -T -c -C RAW'
```

How to Export to csv using above command with header like `Client Code`, `Client Name` and `Total balance`?

Kindly suggest sql Query

Comment: Instead of `select * from TESTING.dbo.TEST` use column names like `select [Client Code],[Client Name], [Total balance] from TESTING.dbo.TEST`

Comment: Column header still not coming in CSV

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom column name for bcp queryout SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287612/custom-column-name-for-bcp-queryout-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

You should do a union with your headers just like this

```
 exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT ''Client_Code'',''Client_Name'',''Total Balance'' union all select cast(Client_Code as nvarchar(50)),Client_Name, cast([Amount] as nvarchar(50)) from TESTING.dbo.TEST" queryout C:\queryoutput.csv -t"," -S"NEMP-HNI6101\SQLEXPRESS" -T -c -C RAW'
```

Comment: Getting fallowing erroroutput
SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'TESTING.dbo.TEST'.
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 8180
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
NULL

Comment: @Mittal do you actually have a table `TESTING.dbo.TEST`?

Comment: Maybe your connected to the right database. Switch database or make sure your query window says TESTING in database. Or make sure you actually have the table TEST and on schema DBO