# BCP copy out failed -- data type conversion & column level collation errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

**Context:** I'm attempting to output the contents of a table in SQL Server to a CSV file via BCP. I'm trying to explicitly name the column headers in the CSV file by performing a UNION ALL so the column headers arent empty.

**Question:** Can someone please share some pointers on why I'm raising these errors, in particular the data type conversion error when I've explicity casted the data types in the query?

```
bcp "select 'col1', 'col2', 'col3' union all select cast(id as varchar(10)), name, cast(someinfo as varchar(28)) from Question1355876" queryout myTable.csv /SmyServer01 /c /t, -T
111
```

I've followed the logic above which was suggested here: [export table to file with column headers (column names) using the bcp utility and SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355876/export-table-to-file-with-column-headers-column-names-using-the-bcp-utility-an)

Below is the T-SQL snippet that keeps failing:

```
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT ''cast(Company_ID as int)'', ''cast(MatterMark_URL as nvarchar(150))'', ''cast(Company_Name as nvarchar(100))'', ''cast(Domain as nvarchar(150))'' UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT cast(id as int), cast(url as nvarchar(150)), cast(company_name as nvarchar(100)), cast(domain as nvarchar(150)) FROM ##jsonparsed" queryout C:\Users\ebarnes\etl_project\company_data.csv -c -T -t'
```

[image]

Comment: The sample you shared showing how to get a header included, is correct. that is a good technique to do so, but it assumed all the data types were compatible. Your data types are not, so you have to address that. See answer below. Also your original header statement where you used ''cast(Company_ID as int)'' is never interpreted as a cast function, its just read as one big string together. Syntactically, it's invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stu is correct about what is happening, but something will need to be casted,  there is more to add. The error you are getting is because you explicitly cast a data type in the 2nd query and so SQL tried to cast the first query (implicitly cast as varchar to start and until SQL encounters the cast in your 2nd query) as an int as well. However, the value in the first column in the first query cannot be converted to int.. it's a varchar string "'cast(Company_ID as int)'".

You have to get the first and 2nd query in your union to be similar data types. You're never going to get the string "cast(Company_ID as int)" to be an integer, I suggest casting your columns in the 2nd query as char/varchar datatypes. You're sending data out to a text file anyway right? You used -c option of bcp, so just make everything in the 2nd match the first, not vice versa.

```
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT ''Company_ID'' UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT cast(id as varchar( 12 ) ) FROM ##jsonparsed" queryout C:\Users\ebarnes\etl_project\company_data.csv -c -T -t'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because one of the values in `Company_ID` is not a number. Like the header.

Try not casting it at all.

Comment: Removing all the data conversion & running the query like so still produces the same errors...

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT ''Company_ID'', ''MatterMark_URL'', ''Company_Name'', ''Domain'' UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT id,url,company_name,domain FROM ##jsonparsed" queryout C:\Users\ebarnes\etl_project\company_data.csv -c -T -t'

Comment: The data conversion you removed here was only the unnecessary data conversion that you didn't need in the first place. The "cast" function that you had in the header was never being interpreted as a function.. you had it inside a literal string. Thats why the error says it couldn't convert "cast( company_id as int)" that was the whole string it tried to convert. The conversion you are missing is the hidden, implicit conversion SQL is TRYING to do because you gave it INT values (in the 2nd query) and varchar values (in the 1st query) and tried to make him put them both in the same column.

Comment: Can only have 1 type of data in a single column... see? :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
    exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT DISTINCT cast(id as int) AS Company_ID, cast(url as nvarchar(150)) AS MatterMark_URL , cast(company_name as nvarchar(100)) AS Company_Name, cast(domain as nvarchar(150)) AS Domain FROM ##jsonparsed" queryout C:\Users\ebarnes\etl_project\company_data.csv -c -T -t'
```

if this fails that means that your global temp table ##jsonparsed has invalid data that could not be converted.

Answer (score 0):

I would just convert it all to nvarchar and I used a function but you need to make sure you use the database name.

```
Create or alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Export]
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @FileName varchar(50),
@bcpCommand varchar(8000)
SET @bcpCommand  = 'bcp "Select * from [Database].dbo.Select()" queryout "C:\temp\Output'
+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 105) + '.csv" -U[Username] -P[Password] -S.\[Instance] -r\n -w'
PRINT @bcpCommand
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
END
```