# BCP - Export CSV with header

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I have run the following query to export my Ms SQL table as CSV. It working good. Now I want to add the field name as the first row. How is it possible?

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select * from test_table" queryout C:\Test_SP\Tom.csv -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

I know that I can specify the names @Red Devil answered. But the table is dynamic, Its fields are not fixed, It will change. I am trying to find a method to fetch the field names from the table definition and prepend it into the result CSV

Comment: Does this answer your question? [export table to file with column headers (column names) using the bcp utility and SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355876/export-table-to-file-with-column-headers-column-names-using-the-bcp-utility-an)

Comment: @SMor , No .because the table is dynamic . I dont know the field names

Comment: The point is still the same - make an effort, do a little searching on the internet. This is not a free <do my work for me> coding service. You have more than sufficient rep to know this. Need to know what columns exist in test_table? You look in the meta-data - sys.columns.

Comment: @SMor This is the first week I am dealing with MS SQL. I  search lot for this but don't find a solution with bcp

Comment: you should modify your title to include the need for dynamic columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select 'col1', 'col2',... union all select * from test_table" queryout C:\Test_SP\Tom.csv -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Comment: Thanks, But my table have dynamically created fields. I am not sure about the field names each time

Comment: Get the column info from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS system view.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes all fields are type of non-numeric.
You will get Conversion failed when converting the `varchar` value '....' to data type `int`.

```sql
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select 'col1', 'col2',... union all select * from test_table" queryout C:\Test_SP\Tom.csv -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```